# Are there any unhealthy situations for Pandavas or Krishna in Mahabaratha?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, pandavas, health

Are there any situations in **Mahabaratha** where either Krishna or any Pandava is/are affected with disease or faced unhealthy situation ?

If there are no such instances, are there any slokas saying that their lifestyle is responsible for such diseaseless life?

Comment: I am not sure what quality of question is this ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto In order to get clarity about their diseaseless lifestyle if they didn't face any such situations other than pranks.

Comment: What is this question? What is your purpose?

Comment: The purpose is to know how they are maintaining health at even odd times if they didn't fall ill.

Comment: It's a good question! I too had this query before. Most likely they also would have gone through the usual health related difficulties which normal humans go through. It could be in lesser magnitude due to better quality of life during then though. In Gita, lord Krishna mentions that one has to pass through the phases of old age and decay. Probably such things are not documented in detail due to less importance.

Answer (score 3):

**Are there any unhealthy situations in Mahabaratha?**

As mentioned in Puranas (such as [Matsya Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/matsya_purana/the_measurement_of_time%20.html), [Kurma Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/kurma_purana/the_yugas_eras.html), [Vayu Purana](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vayu_purana/yugas.html)..) and in [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a068.htm), there were very less or no disease in *Satya Yuga* or *Krita Yuga* and in *Treta Yuga*.

Disease came to be known in *Dvapara Yuga* and it affected few people in Dvapara  and it's widely found in *Kali Yuga*.

We can see few instances in **Mahabharata** where some one had disease. For example,

> **Vichitravirya** died due to **phthisis/tuberculosis/yakṣmā**. ~Discussed in [How did Vichitravirya die?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8253/how-did-vichitravirya-die)

We also find few references of **dropsy**, **leprosy** and few other **skin disease** in Puranas.

So, there were few unhealthy situations in earlier Yugas and/or in Mahabharata.

---

**Are there any slokas saying that their lifestyle is responsible for such diseaseless life?**

[Vayu Purana - Chapter 8](https://archive.org/stream/VayuPurana.Vol.1/Vayu%20Purana.%20Vol.%201#page/n118/mode/1up) deals with this in detail. From [abridged version](http://www.gloriousindia.com/scriptures/puranas/vayu_purana/yugas.html) of Vayu Purana,

> In Satya Yuga, people lived on juice that came out of the bowels of the earth. This juice was so miraculous that old age and **disease were unknown**.

Comment: But the question is specific to Pandavas or Krishna, while your answer....

Comment: @hanugm is your Q limited to 6 persons (5 Pandavas & Krishna) only or it's general for all major characters in Mahabharat...

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto let the OP reply...if that's the case then it might be a partial answer or may be deleted if it's irrelevant in your/OP's/other's opinion...

Comment: My intention is to know among the 6, but your answer is informative, which includes them as well;

Comment: @YDS Don't delete it, it is not irrelevant...